# LINQ Get Latest Record from Multiple Records to List

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table as

StudentName / Classroom / GradeA / GradeB / GradeC / GradeDate

The students classrooms are fixed so that column never changes.

Each student has multiple GradeA, GradeB and GradeC values with different GradeDate.

```
public virtual IList<ClassroomDetail> GetLatestClassroomDetail(string classroom)
    {

        var query = from pc in _classroomDetailRepository.Table
                   where pc.Classroom == classroom
                   select pc;

        var result = new List<ClassroomDetail>(query);

        return result;
    }
```

Above query returns everything and there are multiple same students in the list.

How can I only get latest values?

Tables:

ClassroomMaster

- Id
- UpdateDate
- Classroom

---

ClassroomDetail

- Id
- Cm_Id (has foreign key with ClassroomMaster Id)
- StudentName
- GradeA
- GradeB
- GradeC
- GradeDate

On Controller

```
var bdetail = _classroomService.GetLatestClassroomDetail(classroom).OrderBy(d => d.StudentName);

            var model = new List<ClassroomDetail>();
            foreach (var pr in bdetail)
            {

                model.Add(new ClassroomDetail
                {
                    Id = pr.Id,
                    Classroom = pr.Classroom,
                    StudentName = pr.StudentName,
                    GradeA = pr.GradeA,
                    GradeB = pr.GradeB,
                    GradeC = pr.GradeC,
                    GradeDate = pr.GradeDate,
                });
            }


            return PartialView(model);
```

Comment: latest value grouping by student ? Can you explain more please.

Comment: Yes, there will be one record per student and only the latest one

Comment: and on my controller I call it as var bdetail = _bunkerPriceService.GetLatestClassroomDetail(classroom).OrderBy(d => d.StudentName);

                var model = new List<ClassroomDetail>();
                foreach (var pr in bdetail)
                {

Comment: Can you add the tables diagram in you question? And explain relations between each tables :)

Comment: I have 2 tables

Comment: First is ClassroomMaster, which is only classroom and update date. 2nd one is ClassroomDetail as above. ClassroomMaster Id is a foreign key for ClassroomDetail Cm_Id

Comment: Edited the question for table info

Comment: @BulutKartal show example data and desired output.

Comment: @Nkosi I edited the question again and added controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will solve your problem

```
     var query = _classroomDetailRepository.Table
        .Where(a => a.Classroom == classroom)             
        .Select(b => b.OrderByDescending(y => y.GradeDate).Take(1).FirstOrDefault());
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution :D

```
 public virtual IList<ClassroomDetail> GetLatestClassroomDetail(string classroom)
    {
        var query = _classroomDetailRepository.Table
            .Where(z => z.Classroom == classroom)
            .GroupBy(x => x.StudentName)                
            .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.GradeDate).Take(1).FirstOrDefault());

        var result = new List<BunkerPriceDetail>(query);

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Probably correct, but redundant `.Take(1)`, since `FirstOrDefault()` only will return at most one record.

Comment: Why was my edit reverted? Am I wrong? If yes I'd like to know why.

Comment: @tinudu ohhh, I guess I accidentally did it. sorry, both works. Thank you!